# libgdx: speed loss on object collision

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I'm trying to build a sample that consists in some circles moving and colliding among themselves. As all the circles have the same attributes and `restitution = 1` and `friction = 0`, I expect that they should bounce eternally always at the same speed. But, instead, some objects slow down:

[image]

World creation:

```
World.setVelocityThreshold(0);
world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);
```

Boundaries:

```
EdgeShape edge = new EdgeShape();
FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
wallFixtureDef.shape = edge;
wallFixtureDef.density = 0;
wallFixtureDef.friction = 0;
wallFixtureDef.restitution = 1;

BodyDef wallBodyDef = new BodyDef();
wallBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;

Body wallsBody = world.createBody(wallBodyDef);

// Bottom
edge.set(1, 1, WIDTH - 1, 1);
wallsBody.createFixture(wallFixtureDef);

// Top
edge.set(1, HEIGTH - 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGTH - 1);
wallsBody.createFixture(wallFixtureDef);

// Left
edge.set(1, 1, 1, HEIGTH - 1);
wallsBody.createFixture(wallFixtureDef);

// Right
edge.set(WIDTH - 1, 1, WIDTH - 1, HEIGTH - 1);
wallsBody.createFixture(wallFixtureDef);
```

Circles:

```
CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
circleShape.setRadius(24);
FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
fixtureDef.density = 1;
fixtureDef.friction = 0;
fixtureDef.restitution = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(i * 70, HEIGTH / 2);

    Body ballBody = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    ballBody.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    ballBody.setBullet(true);
    ballBody.setLinearVelocity(300, 120);
}
```

I've also tried without: `World.setVelocityThreshold(0);` and without `ballBody.setBullet(true);` but it does the same.

So, how could I achieve it? If `restitution = 1` and `friction = 0`, what's causing this behavior?

**UPDATE:**

Finally it works as expected. There are two main problems: float precision and too large initial velocity (box2d has a maximum speed limit).

I have reproduced the example but with much smaller units:

```
radius = 10 
density = 0.1f
velocity = (10, 10)
```

This does not prevent the precision error in the positions of the circles, which will end up not being perfectly aligned. But it prevents the system from losing speed.

With these values, once the circles are not aligned, depending on the angle at which they collide, if one slows down the other one accelerates. That is, the momentum of the system is maintained.

In the original example, the problem is that I use large units. Circles' initial velocity is limited to the maximum that box2d allows. In this situation, when the circles collide without being aligned, one may slow down but the other one can not accelerate (because it's already at max speed) and, therefore, the system loses speed. The momentum of the system is not maintained.

The first correction is to use smaller units, so that the precision error is lower and values does not exceed the limits of box2d.

[image]

The second, only valid for this concrete example, would be to correct the position of the circles once the simulation of physics has been made.

```
world.step(STEP_TIME, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS);

float y = bodies[0].getPosition().y;
for (Body body : bodies) {
    body.setTransform(body.getPosition().x, y, body.getAngle());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A greater-than-zero linear damping setting on a body is meant for slowing down that body.

Given the sources you've shown and that [box2d sources show that by default the linear damping is 0](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h#L61), it does not appear that the linear damping setting is the culprit. I would re-check the application sources and the sources that libgdx is built from, to confirm that indeed nothing is setting the linear damping on dynamic bodies to non-zero values.

On the other hand, if linear damping was set to non zero by a default somewhere, I'd expect all the circles to slow down (equally, at least in theory) and your picture appears to show only one circle having a noticeable speed change: a speed loss.

So I believe something less intentional (and more esoteric) is at work.

At least some of what you are seeing will come about from the use of [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). The inaccuracy of floating-point arithmetic gets compounded by the bouncing that the circles are doing against the wall and each other. In this situation, the circles — at different `x` and `y` locations — will sometimes get slightly different collision response errors that destabilizes the orderly setup they start with.

For an elaborate explanation of problems that can crop up in the use of floating point arithmetic, see: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

As to what you can do to prevent this, there aren't any easy solutions that I'm aware of. It'd be easier to mitigate the problem. Some possible mitigations could be:

- Rerunning the simulation with different sizes, distances, densities, and velocities to see which combination can optimize the simulation best for you. If speed loss is more the concern than the general disarray that the simulation devolves to, increasing masses/densities would be the first thing I'd try of these.
- Decreasing step delta times and calling step more often.
- Decreasing the number of circles in your simulation.
- Replacing the use of `float` with `double` in all the Box2D source code and rebuilding the Java implementation on top of your modified Box2D.

Replacing the use of float with a tried and proven fixed point integer implementation should eliminate the floating point inaccuracies but at the expense of introducing different kinds of inaccuracies and taking significant more work than replacing the use of floats with doubles would. Another tack you could try that should fix the problem would be to override the collision responses in contact listener callbacks such that you account for the inaccuracy and factor this back into the computations. If there are no other interactions that you want to simulate, I think it'd be easier to force the known paths in your contact listener code rather than try to correct the errors.

If you're expecting 100% Newton's cradle like results, that can be harder to achieve in part for the floating point arithmetic reason I've mentioned. Note that Box2D-like physics simulations often don't provide completely Newton's cradle-like results (for example see [this](https://youtu.be/leDccYvnRzU) video on YouTube). There are some discussions that I've found on the web about this such as [Newton's cradle](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=1584) on the Bullet Physics forum which may offer more insight or ideas. Incidentally, I have [a Newton's cradle demo in the test bed of the physics engine I've been working on](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/PlayRho/tree/master/Testbed/Tests#newtonscradlehpp) which provides a lot of runtime tweak-ability and also demonstrates non-Newton's cradle like results.

Sorry if this seems like bad news but I do hope it can help anyway.

Comment: I knew there would be some inaccuracy due to floating arithmetic, but I'm surprised it's so notorious. Running the simulation with other parameters may help a little but the problem persists. I will try to correct the loss of speed after the collision in a listener.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It inspired me to think more about the problem and I've updated my answer in the hopes of increasing it's usefulness. In particular it sounds like the disarray the sim gets to isn't as much a concern for you as the circle that gets slower than the rest. Increasing the density/mass of all the circles seems like the first mitigation I'd try if the odd ball circle's speed was my primary concern. I'll be interested in hearing what results you see are.

Comment: Another thought... If the contacts persisted even after the circle's AABBs no longer overlapped, that might help conserve energy of the system since they in part do that while they exist. Enlarging the `b2_aabbExtension` in the Box2D settings file and rebuilding with a much larger extension may buy provide that. Hmm...

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborate response! 
So far, I have tried with different simulation parameters such as: step time, dimensions, initial velocity, density... With some of them, the simulation works apparently well up to a few minutes. I don't expect a perfect simulation, but at least that the circles never stop or lose speed. I'll be happy with an "apparently correct" simulation.

Comment: Whenever I have a free moment, I'll try to use listeners to capture the object's speed on 'beginContact' and restore it on 'endContact'. Based on your explanation, I think it is the only solution to have a stable and infinite simulation.